# Error: GET js file net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, http-status-code-404

I know that this question is not first but I don't know where to look for solution.
I have an express backend server. It has to render HTML page with main.js in it when it launches.

*app.js* code:

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
// <...>

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

var listener = app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
  
});
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



module.exports = app;
```

*public/index.html* code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Fetch Travels</title>
    <style>
        #play {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="play">search</button>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**public/main.js** obviosly is a client script that is not found on a server but found in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to follow the correct folders structure: **Public should in src** dir
instead of this (that you have):

```
- public
  - main.js
  - ingex.html
- src
  - index.js
  ...
```

you have to this

```
- src
  - index.js
  - public
    - main.js
    - ingex.html
  ...
```

And second you need this line in express configuration in *src/index.js* to let the server to deliver extra files (not index.html only)

```
app.use("/public/", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and finally the html tag:

```
<script src="public/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to something like this

```
<script src="/main.js" type="module"></script>
```